# AWK to find two patterns and print to execute as command

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I have a command: `./start.sh version`

I have a file `1.txt` where version is specified.

```
some_pattern=something
some_pattern=something
Fix_Version=install_v.1
some_pattern=something
some_pattern=something
```

Have another file `install.sh` which executes the command but I want that file to capture the version and execute the command.

```
somecommands
somecommands
(./start.sh version)
somecommands
somecommands
```

So, the result should be like this: `./start.sh install_v.1` and execute it. Read from both the files search for only `./start.sh` in `install.sh` and in `1.txt` look for version and execute the command `./start.sh install_v.1`.

Comment: I understand why you have to fetch the value from `1.txt` but why do you have to search for the line `(./start.sh version)` in install.sh just to run `./start.sh <value_took_from_1.txt>` when you could just run it immediately? Please give an answer to that to clarify your purpose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [match two patterns execute the command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551824/match-two-patterns-execute-the-command). Don't just re-post questions that get closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this awk:

```
awk -F '[ =]+' 'FNR==NR && $1=="Fix_Version"{ver=$2;next} FNR!=NR{if ($1~/start\.sh/) $0 = $1 " " ver ")"; print $0}' a.txt install.sh
somecommands
somecommands
(./start.sh install_v.1)
somecommands
somecommands
```